# GCE list of required domains to clear firewall

Tags: google-compute-engine

with my current firewall settings at the host http/https connections need to be on cleared lists, so I can't even do the curl download of the sdk. I can't seem to find a list of required names for setting up the google cloud sdk. Perhaps accounts.google.com for oauth token, cloud.google.com/* for the sdk 
In the hopes of avoiding a game of whack-a-mole and just requesting a cleared list all at once, can this be found anywhere, if more than what I wrote are required?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find any official article listing the domains that are used to interact with Google Cloud, but this list should cover everything:

- accounts.google.com
- cloud.google.com
- sdk.cloud.google.com
- storage.cloud.google.com
- googleapis.com
- storage.googleapis.com
- console.developers.google.com
- appengine.google.com